# Как избежать деления на ноль на уровне SQL-запроса?

Tags: php, mysql, алгоритм

Есть код, который выводит топ относительно рейтинга (соотношения количества убийств к смертям, однако когда количество последних равно 0, то выскакивает сабж)

```
$query = 'SELECT
            `player_name`,
            `S`,
            `D`
          FROM
            `accounts`
          ORDER BY
            (`S` / `D`) DESC
          LIMIT 5';
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) 
{
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    { 
        $i += 1;
        printf(
         "<p class='%s'>%s<br><span>%0.1f рейтинг</span></p>",
         Convert($i),
         $row['player_name'],
         $row['S'] / $row['D']);
    }
    $result->close(); 
}
```

Можно ли как-то изменить его, оставив прежний функционал? У кого рейтинг выше, тот выше в топе, логично же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно модифицировать условие сортировки, заменяя выражение `S / D` на `S`, если `D` принимает значение 0

```
SELECT
  player_name,
  S,
  D
FROM
  accounts
ORDER BY
  IF(D = 0, S, (S / D)) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Аналогичную проверку можно поставит при выводе или сразу вычислить рейтинг в SQL-запросе

```
SELECT
  player_name,
  IF(D = 0, S, (S / D)) AS rating
FROM
  accounts
ORDER BY
  IF(D = 0, S, (S / D)) DESC
LIMIT 5
```